# How to query across multiple rows in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm saving dynamic objects (objects of which I do not know the type upfront) using the following 2 tables in Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS objects(
    id UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    user_id UUID NOT NULL,

    name TEXT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS object_values(
    id UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    event_id UUID NOT NULL,

    param TEXT NOT NULL,
    value TEXT NOT NULL,
);
```

So for instance, if I have the following objects:

```
dog = [
  { breed: "poodle", age: 15, ...},
  { breed: "husky", age: 9, ...},
}
monitors = [
  { manufacturer: "dell", ...},
}
```

It will live in the DB as follows:

```
-- objects
| id | user_id | name    |
|----|---------|---------|
| 1  | 1       | dog     |
| 2  | 2       | dog     |
| 3  | 1       | monitor |

-- object_values
| id | event_id | param        | value  |
|----|----------|--------------|--------|
| 1  | 1        | breed        | poodle |
| 2  | 1        | age          | 15     |
| 3  | 2        | breed        | husky  |
| 4  | 2        | age          | 9      |
| 5  | 3        | manufacturer | dell   |
```

Note, these tables are big (hundreds of millions). Generally optimised for writing.
What would be a good way of querying/filtering objects based on multiple object params? For instance: Select the number of all `husky` dogs above the age of `10` per unique user.

I also wonder whether it would have been better to denormalise the tables and collapse the params onto a JSON column (and use gin indexes).

Are there any standards I can use here?

Comment: "*What would be a good way of querying/filtering objects based on multiple object params?*" - use separate tables that are optimised for reading. Do not fear to create tables dynamically.

Comment: Hey @Bergi do you mind expanding a bit on your answer. Do you mean different read/write db replicas? For now, unfortunately, that's not an option. Also, there's no cap on how many types of objects I'll get. How would I make generic db queries if I start making tables dynamically?

Comment: I only meant different tables in a denormalised schema (which you kinda have already anyway, using EAV, so let's introduce some duplication :P), not database replicas. And yes, an unlimited number of dynamic tables will be hard to manage, but it would allow you to put indices on them where you care about performance and it would allow you to write standard relational queries (`SELECT user_id, count(*) FROM husky WHERE age > 10 GROUP BY user_id`).

Comment: Ahh, I understand @Bergi! Yes, having different tables is still an option we're considering, unfortunately, not a change we can do now. Would you say JSONB (along with 1 gin index) would be a better option than using this EAV approach?

Comment: Unless you have a requirement for writing multiple attributes for the same object independently (at different times) and optimise for writing speed, JSONB probably makes it more efficient to retrieve the whole document and to match multiple conditions, than using EAV. But more importantly, JSONB also makes writing queries simpler :-) (Disclaimer: performance needs to measured, I'm only guessing).

Comment: I'd probably also look into alternatives to Postgres, graph databases and triple stores might be better optimised for this kind of work. Sounds like switching wouldn't be an option for you either, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Select the number of all husky dogs above the age of 10 per unique user*" - The following query would do it.

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT event_id) AS num_husky_dogs_older_than_10
FROM       objects       o
INNER JOIN object_values ov
        ON o.id_ = ov.event_id
       AND o.name_ = 'dog'
GROUP BY o.user_id
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN ov.param = 'age' 
                 AND ov.value_::integer >= 10 THEN 1 END) = 1
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN ov.param = 'breed'
                 AND ov.value_ = 'husky'      THEN 1 END) = 1;
```

Since your queries are most likely affected by having always the same `JOIN` operation between these two tables on the same fields, would be good to have a **indices** on:

- the fields you join on ("*objects.id*", "*object_values.event_id*")
- the fields you filter on ("*objects.name*", "*object_values.param*", "*object_values.value_*")

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gxXmK1FkeobGjZtYETXDyg/3).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, i think this will include all dogs, not just huskeys

Comment: Right, I must have missed the "husky" condition, check the updated query. I've included a demo in PostgreSQL too.

Comment: Hey, the query provided doesn't work as expected. I've forked the example here, where I expect the count to be 1. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gxXmK1FkeobGjZtYETXDyg/0 I have a feeling that to do it properly, I'd need to denormalise the tables. What do you think?

Comment: Hmm, I thought the fork link that I gave in my above comment had 1 husky. In any case, it's returning 2 instead of the expected 1. It seems it counts the number of parameters of the matched object, instead of the sum of huskies

Comment: You're correct, I thought you were referring to your sample data. Try with `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)` >> [Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gxXmK1FkeobGjZtYETXDyg/1).

Comment: That works! do you mind explaining how this works? My understanding was that because of the join the two parameters would live in 2 different rows. So in a way you're querying across 2 rows? Do you think this would be more efficient for write-heavy tables or is it better to stick with a JSONB column instead and gin_indexes?

Comment: You'll get as many rows as the amount of existing rows per "*event_id*". This is due to the `CASE` expressions that will generate 1 when the corresponding condition is true, NULL otherwise (see [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gxXmK1FkeobGjZtYETXDyg/2)). Then we compute the `MAX` of these fields, by partitioning on user_id, and if we don't get 1 on both these fields, the value is not returned. If you had three properties for that event_id, we would have had 3 rows instead of 2.

Comment: Can't tell in advance if using JSONB columns with gin_indices would be more efficient than using tables with indices, although you could try experimenting and observing the difference in carrying out the same task, once by querying tables, another time by querying jsonb fields. Use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to look at query plans and execution times.

Comment: Note that there's a further typo in the query: `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)` will count if a user has any dog with those conditions, while `COUNT(DISTINCT event_id)` will count how many dogs per user. Reading again your description, it looks like you're in need of the second one. I have updated the answer and the demo accordingly.